# Which assignment defines a bijection here? And what is its inverse? And why?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

In order to make an argument given in *A First Course in Modular Forms* by Diamond-Shurman to count the cusps of $Γ_0 (N)$ in the context of modular curves more rigorous, I want to prove that there is a bijection:

$$\bigcup_{d | N} \{d\} × Φ \big(\gcd (d,\tfrac{N}{d})\big) → M_N/Λ_N$$

where $Φ(n)$ denotes the set of coprime integers between $1, …, n$ and on the other hand:
\begin{align}
M_N = \{v ∈ (ℤ/N)^2;\; \operatorname{ord} v = N\},\quad \text{and} \quad
Λ_N = 〈\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}y&0\\0&y^{-1}\end{bmatrix};\; y ∈ (ℤ/N)^×〉.
\end{align}
So $Λ_N$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_2 (ℤ/N)$.
My main questions are:

> What assignment gives me a bijection between these sets and what is its inverse?

**Edit**: The following doesn’t work out at all …

> Now, my first thought was that simply:
>   $$ (d,x) ↦ Λ_N · \begin{bmatrix}\overline{x}\\\overline{d}\end{bmatrix}$$
>   should do the trick, because:
>   Let $\begin{bmatrix}\overline{a} & \overline{c}\end{bmatrix}^T ∈ M_N/Λ_N$, assuming $c ≤ N$.
>   Then setting $d = \gcd(c,N)$ gives an $x ∈ Φ(N)$ such that $c = xd$, so:
>   $$Λ_N · \begin{bmatrix}\overline{xa}\\\overline{d}\end{bmatrix} = Λ_N · \begin{bmatrix}\overline{a}\\\overline{c}\end{bmatrix}$$
>   But now I am stuck and I don’t know how to argue any further to obtain surjectivity.
>   I also don’t see how this assignment could be inverted. Is it even the correct one?

…, because for $N = 48$ and $d = 12$ the map given by me isn’t even well-defined, since then $(12,3) ∈ \{12\} × Φ (4)$, but $16·\begin{bmatrix}\overline{12} & \overline{3} \end{bmatrix}^T = 0$, so $\begin{bmatrix}\overline{12} & \overline{3} \end{bmatrix}^T \notin M_{48}$.

**Therefore**: I need something different.
Any ideas?

Comment: I just remembered, for $N = 48$ and $d = 12$ the map given by me isn’t even well-defined, since then $(12,3) ∈ \{12\} × Φ (4)$, but $16·\begin{bmatrix}\overline{12} & \overline{3} \end{bmatrix} = 0$, so $\begin{bmatrix}\overline{12} & \overline{3} \end{bmatrix} \notin M_N$